# Flask SQLAlchemy Query Only working the first time

Tags: python, postgresql, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to check if a tag is already stored in a table. The query finds the first tag but not the second and both already exit in the table.

```
        tags = form.tags.data
        tags = tags.split(sep=",")
        tag: str
        for tag in tags:
            # Register the tag if it is not already stored
            tag_aux = Tags.get_by_tag(tag, language)
            if tag_aux is None:
                tag_id = Tags(None, tag.strip(), language).save()
                TagsPosts(post.id, tag_id).save()
            else:
                TagsPosts(post.id, tag_aux.id).save()
        # commit
        TagsPosts.commit()
```

The loop goes over a list of tags retrived from the form and checks if it already exists.
tag_aux gets the value if it is already present in the db.

```
#  Table Mapping
__tablename__ = 'tags'
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
description = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
language_id = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)

def __init__(self, arg_id, description, language_id):
    self.id = arg_id
    self.description = description
    self.language_id = language_id

#  Gets a tag by description and language
@staticmethod
def get_by_tag(description, language_id):
    """Used to check if a tag already exists"""
    return Tags.query.filter_by(description=description,language_id=language_id).first()
```

surprisingly the first tag is found but not the second one so tag_aux gets a None in the second loop.

1. Query

```
   kwargs = {dict: 2} {'description': 'Te', 'language_id': 'ES'}
   self = {BaseQuery} SELECT tags.id AS tags_id, tags.description AS tags_description,      tags.language_id AS tags_language_id \nFROM tags
```

2. Query

```
  kwargs = {dict: 2} {'description': ' Inglaterra', 'language_id': 'ES'}
  self = {BaseQuery} SELECT tags.id AS tags_id, tags.description AS tags_description,   tags.language_id AS tags_language_id \nFROM tags
```

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PyBA8.png)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the second query there is an extra space with the description `'description': ' Inglaterra'`. It should be `'description': ' Inglaterra'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment, the queried string is contained extra space. I would fix the code as follows (and minor refactoring)

```py
tags: List[str] = form.tags.data.split(",")
for tag in tags:
    tag = tag.strip()
    # Register the tag if it is not already stored
    tag_aux = Tags.get_by_tag(tag, language)
    if tag_aux is None:
        tag_id = Tags(None, tag, language).save()
        TagsPosts(post.id, tag_id).save()
    else:
        TagsPosts(post.id, tag_aux.id).save()
# commit
TagsPosts.commit()
```